# Mistakenly removed scsi-drive device files

Tags: linux, udev, devices

I mistakenly removed my sd* device files via the following command:
rm /dev/sd*.
Is it possible to recreate the device files via mknod?

Comment: Yes it is possible to recreate them. You just need to rescan the SCSI bus. The command to rescan for new hardware depends mainly on the manufacturer of your hardware. For instance, at the times of HP DL380 machines, there was `hp_rescan -a`. Don't know what hardware you have, hence don't know which exact command you need to run.

Answer (score 3):

You can try running

```
# udevadm trigger
```

Or restart the udev daemon.

Answer (score 1):

If you have a file named `MAKEDEV` ( yes upper case) in `/dev`  directory, you can try to run it.

HP UX use `insf -e`.